# Bash Echo Not Printing

Tags: bash, printing, echo

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A keyPair

while IFS=, read key value; do
    keyPair[$key]=$value
done <$2

while read line; do
    for char in $line; do
        decoded=${keyPair[$char]}
        echo -n "$decoded"
    done
done <$1
```

this is my code above. I am trying to output text which reads from a file and replaces words in the file corresponding to those in an associative array.(e.g. AA: {waste: run}, the program will replace all instances of 'waste' with 'run'). I am tying to echo the output without a new line. I assume this works with the echo -n, however my console does not output anything. However if i run the same script with just an echo without -n, my program outputs the following:

```
zoo
garage
water
mountain

run
father
zoo
underwater
fast

run
walk

foo
fast
father
```

I would like to make it so that it looks like this

```
zoo garage water mountain

run father zoo underwater fast

run walk

foo fast father
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Check your script for DOS line endings. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info.

Comment: Hmm, I think that did the trick. I did have DOS line endings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stemmed from having DOS line endings in my input txt files. Fixing the DOS line endings seemed to have fixed all my issues.

Read more: stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info